# Every basis of the vector space of all three by three matrices has exactly 9 vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I answer this question as a true or false?

Edit:Answer is stated as True

Comment: If you're doing a course in finite-dimensional linear algebra, there should be a **very prominent** result about bases of vector spaces that should help you here.

Comment: For a start, never mind the "every".  Can you give one example of a basis for the space of $3\times3$ matrices?

Comment: How about the standard basis, (1,0,0)(0,1,0)(0,0,1)? that has three vectors

Comment: Those are not $3\times3$ matrices.

Comment: But the standard basis is one such basis for a 3x3 Matrix. Unless I am understanding this question wrong.

Comment: Remember that a $3\times3$ matrix is called a vector in this scenario as your vector space is made up of these types of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true.
Without loss of generality, you can consider any $3\times3$ matrix, a $9$-dimensional vector i.e., there is a bijection between $3\times3$ matrices and vectors in $\Bbb R^9$.

Any basis in $\Bbb R^9$ has $9$ vectors because more vectors would result in the vectors being linearly dependent and less vectors would results in not being able to span $\Bbb R^9$.

So, any basis for the vector space of $3\times3$ matrices would have $9$ vectors.

Comment: In future, please use MathJax to format your answers. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide.